# Docbook, turn off table numbering

Tags: xml, customization, docbook

As the title reflects I want to turn off the numbering of tables.

The reason is that the tables already have custom numbering (nested in the xml code).

Any suggestion is apperciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Simple solution:*

You can use the `<informaltable>` element for creating tables without any title at all. If you need a title, embrace the informaltable with a `<simplesect>`.

*Not-so-simple solution:*

If you really need `<table>` elements, read this description how to customize your stylesheet accordingly:

http://www.sagehill.net/docbookxsl/PrintTableStyles.html#TablesUnnumbered

Comment: I got close to the solution thanks for you! But, unfortunately, I got this result after I modified my stylesheet: http://i52.tinypic.com/15cgj7m.png